# Visual Studio 2013 - Tab close behavior

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tabs, customization

I've been using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition for several months now and have one small problem. When I close a tab with middle click, it closes on button press down, not on button press up.

If this doesn't make sense, what I can use as an example is the tab close behavior in Firefox. When you hold middle click over a tab, it doesn't close the tab immediately, it only closes when you release that button.

Is there any way to replicate this behavior in Visual Studio 2013? I frequently close the wrong tab, but happen to hold middle click when I do it, so this change would help me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way of doing this in Visual Studio but you could try using [Mouse and Keyboard Center 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35558) (a free download from Microsoft).

According to Tech Republic (emphasis mine):

> Although this basic functionality is helpful, the utility's best feature is that **it allows for application specific button assignments**. As such, the right mouse button could be assigned one function in File Explorer and a different function in Microsoft Office.

Comment: That application only functions when you have specific Microsoft devices installed. I, using my employer's hardware, don't have any.

Comment: @Dispenser - Are you able to configure your mouse at all? Maybe ask your company's IT desk if you can install software for whatever brand mouse you're using.

Comment: It's a basic Dell mouse. I've looked at a few options for the functionality I want, but they don't appear to have it.

Comment: @Dispenser - Try looking on superuser.com. Someone has probably had this issue before.

Comment: I figured this was fairly relevant to stack overflow instead of super user, but I suppose the downvote on my question says that someone disagrees. Can't find anything similar on superuser.

Comment: I think this might have been OK here since it's a question about a programming tool but it doesn't look like the option/feature you need exists in Visual Studio. I didn't down-vote though so I can't say why you got one.